# Don't repeat yourself vs do only one thing in a method

Tags: design, python, testing

I am currently writing some test cases in python. I often end up calling the same two or three lines of code at the start of a test case in order to get the program I am testing going. For example:

```
test_something_foo():
    call_method_a(x)
    call_method_b(y)
    # test some stuff

test_something_bar():
    call_method_a(x)
    call_method_b(y)
    # test some other stuff
```

This means I am repeating those two lines together over and over. So I thought to extract like so:

```
test_something_foo():
    call_method_a_and_b(x,y)
    # test some stuff

test_something_bar():
    call_method_a_and_b(x,y)
    # test some other stuff

call_method_a_and_b(x, y):
    call_method_a()
    call_method_b()
```

But I am not sure if this is a good idea. On the one hand it solves the "don't repeat yourself" principle, but doesn't my method "call_method_a_and_b()" violate the principle of "a method should do one thing, and one thing only". How do you reconcile those two seemingly conflicting design principles??

Comment: What are A and B are in this case? Balancing principals is often a matter of context.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) is for. It is executed automatically before running each test, and can be used to initialize class fields and properties or set up the environment (in a case of integration and system tests).

As for the one thing principle, it is perfectly fine to have a method A which calls methods B and C if the method A is acting on a different level of abstraction than B and C.

What would be a violation of one thing principle is to put the *bodies* of the method B and C *inside* the method A.

Example: in order to create a product, you need to:

1. Store the product in the database,
2. Store the product image on disk.

Those two actions can be put in a method `createProduct` implemented like this:

```
def createProduct(self):
    self.db.storeProduct(product_model)
    self.moveImage(product_model.image_upload_path)
```

The method `createProduct` performs one thing: it creates a product. On the other hand, if the method actually went in the details of database manipulation and files storage, then it would be doing multiple things.

Answer (score 2):

If you can think of a better name than `call_method_a_and_b()`, a name that is a single concept, then it isn't a violation of the 'one thing' principle.

If you are calling `a` and `b` in that order for different reasons in `foo` than in `bar`, so one of the two call sites might need to change while the other stays the same, then you aren't violating DRY.  (For instance, `foo` might need to change to call `b` and then `a`, while `bar` needs to keep the original order.)

So, evaluate whether it is a coincidence that you're calling `a` and `b` in that order, or whether the pair of them in that order represents an idea or concept.  Don't make a method if it's a coincidence, and do if it's an idea.  Just make sure not to name the method `call_method_a_and_b()`.